# From file explorer into Vim buffer instead of window

Tags: vim

I'm on Windows 7. If I open a file from Windows Explorer then it opens as a different instance of Vim. I'd like it to just open as a buffer inside the existing instance of Vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Launch_files_in_new_tabs_under_Windows) manual. It's not a perfect solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary that you do it from the Windows Explorer?

Because as stated [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_buffer_FAQ), the correct way of loading a buffer into a vim instance is by using command `:badd` giving as parameter the path of the file you want. This will add the buffer to the buffer list without openning for editing. If what you want is to actually edit then you can use command `:e`.